# Type error creating data frame from list of series

Tags: deedle

This works:

```
let df = Frame(["s1";"s2"],
         [ series["a"=>1;"b"=>2]; series["a"=>3;"b"=>4] ])
```

But if I do this:

```
let theSeries = [ series["a"=>1;"b"=>2]; series["a"=>3;"b"=>4] ]
let df2 = Frame(["s1";"s2"], theSeries)
```

I get the error:

```
error FS0001: The type 'Series<string,int> list' is not compatible with the type 'seq<ISeries<'a>>'
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail to what you're trying to accomplish with this code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit subtle. When you pass the list directly to the constructor, F# infers the type of the list based on the type required by the constructor, which is `list<ISeries<_>>`.

When you instead create the list first, the type is inferred from the specific series and you get `list<Series<int, float>>`.

You can solve this by adding a type annotation:

```
let theSeries : list<ISeries<_>> = [ series["a"=>1;"b"=>2]; series["a"=>3;"b"=>4] ]
let df2 = Frame(["s1";"s2"], theSeries)
```

Or you can use (perhaps nicer) `ofColumns` function:

```
[ "s1" => series["a"=>1;"b"=>2]
  "s2" => series["a"=>3;"b"=>4] ]
|> Frame.ofColumns
```